# Flutter. Свойства параметров

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

Всем привет. Я новичок во flutter. Работаю в vs code.
Мягко говоря, мешает незнание свойств для параметров виджетов. Может есть какое-то расширение с подсказками или автодополнением, которое я пропустил?

Вот пара простых примеров:
Допустим, я использую Scaffold у которого есть секция AppBar. Откуда бы мне узнать, что туда следует записывать

> AppBar: **AppBar(title: ...)**
> ?

Да, конечно можно пойти в документацию и там в примере будет нужная строка, но зачастую многие свойства в примере не упоминаются, а справка по свойству выдает что-то примерно такое: *final PreferredSizeWidget appBar*

Или, допустим, свойство margin. Я по старому опыту пытаюсь написать

> margin: 10

Тогда как требуется EdgeInsets.all/only/simmetric(10)

И такое на каждом шагу.

Answer (score 2):

При наведении на параметр всплывает документация. Чаше всего там есть пример того что можно передать. Если примера нет то надо смотреть на тип параметра и передавать ему его. Зачастую этот тип абстрактный, значит надо передать реализацию этого типа. Чаше всего нужный вам параметр можно найти по названию. Ну и знать основные виджеты и их параметры тоже нужно...